# Highcharts addaxis measure dynamically

Tags: highcharts, axis

I want to add yAxis dynamically.

```
chart.addAxis({ 
        id: serie.options.id,
        title: {
        text: serie.name
    },
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: serie.color,
    opposite: false,
});
```

the code above, adds only line. I need to add measure too. How can i add specific measure for a serie?

Comment: By 'mesure' you mean data ?

Comment: there is default measure, but i can't add measure of "mhp_oy" http://i.imgur.com/hxN56g9.png

Comment: You need to assign data to that axis. What is highcharts supposed to put there if you do not tell it what it is?

Comment: Fair enough, its working when i add serie. I didn't put data because its already on screen. However, i'll add serie then remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

For new axis to show *measure* (AKA scale and labels) you need to set this axis as an `yAxis` for a series or link this new axis to an existing one, that is showing labels.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    }]
  }, function(chart) {
    chart.addAxis({
      id: 'serie.options.id',
      title: {
        text: 'serie.name'
      },
      lineWidth: 2,
      //lineColor: serie.color,
      opposite: false,
      //linkedTo: 0
    });
    chart.addSeries({
        data: [42,2,4,0],
      yAxis: 1
    });
  });
});
```

Example with:

- linkedTo: http://jsfiddle.net/u90dLbc6/1/
- assigned series: http://jsfiddle.net/u90dLbc6/0/